# Generating HTML report from browser

Tags: code-coverage, intern

When using intern locally in the browser through `intern/client.html?config=test/intern`,
is it possible to generate an html report file if my `test/intern.js` file is defined as:

```
define({
    ...
    reporters: ['html']
});
```

Or the is the file generation possible only when running from node?

Also, how can I set the location where the report file will be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guessed, file generation is only supported from Node (using `intern-client` or `intern-runner`). The browser client is not capable of generating files, and in any case the 'html' reporter provided with Intern can only generate HTML output in a browser, so currently the only built-in way to get an HTML test report file is to manually save the report from the browser.